# how to use the pattern option to validate a phone number in grails <g:field type=text

Tags: validation, grails

I want users to just enter ten digits without punctuation. I have tried the patterns below. In each case a popup asks me to "Please match the requested format". I may switch to a jquery solution, but I am still curious why this isn't working?

Thanks for any insights,
Sue

```
<label for="cellPhone">
            <g:message code="employees.cellPhone.label" default="Cell Phone" />
        </label>
        <g:field type="text" pattern="~/[0-9]{10}/" name="cellPhone1" placeholder="10-digit cell including area code" ></g:field>
        <g:field type="text" pattern="~[0-9]{10}" name="cellPhone2" placeholder="10-digit cell including area code" ></g:field>
        <g:field type="text" pattern="~/\\d{10}/" name="cellPhone3" placeholder="10-digit cell including area code" ></g:field>
        <g:field type="text" pattern="~\\d{10}" name="cellPhone4" placeholder="10-digit cell including area code" ></g:field>
        <g:field type="text" pattern="~/\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d/" name="cellPhone5" placeholder="10-digit cell including area code" ></g:field>
        <g:field type="text" pattern="~\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d" name="cellPhone6" placeholder="10-digit cell including area code" ></g:field>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `~/` as [this is a client side thing](http://html5pattern.com/Phones)

```
<g:field type="text"
         pattern="[0-9]{10}"
         name="cellPhone1"
         placeholder="10-digit cell including area code"/>
```